# C++ Eigen Vector infer vector size at compile time for class

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I'm trying to make a wrapper class for Eigen::Matrix. It should take in a pointer to a static size eigen vector (matrix with 1 row), and should return a copy when the getValue() function is called. This is what I currently have

```
template<std::size_t N>
class InputV
{
public:

    InputV(const Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1>* in) : in_(in)
    {

    }

    Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1>
    getValue() const
    {
        return *in_;
    }

private:
    const Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1>* in_;
};

TEST_CASE("dummy")
{
    Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1> a;
    
    InputV<10> in(&a);
}
```

However, I need to explicitly tell it the size twice, once during the initialization of the source pointer, a second time when creating the InputV wrapper class. Is there a way to have the InputV infer the size N, so I don't have to specify it twice?

Thanks!

Comment: `decltype(in_)` ?

Comment: Hm, I'm not familiar with that specifier. I'm looking at it, but could you explain a bit more on how I could use it to help? Thanks!

Comment: You can replace the ctor by `InputV(decltype(in_) in) : in_(in) {}`, however your attribute `in_` must be declared before the ctor (i.e. higher in your class definition).

Comment: Hm, I didn't know decltype could do that, looks really neat, thanks!

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `decltype(in_)` will return `Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1> const * &`, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C++17, you can use [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (and deduction guides, but you don't need them in this case):

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1> a;

auto x = InputV(&a);
InputV y(&a);
```

If you're using an older C++ version (i.e. C++11 or C++14), you can use a helper function. This works because functions can deduce template arguments in all C++ versions:

```
template <std::size_t N>
InputV<N> makeInputV (Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> const * m) {
  return InputV<N>(m);
}

Eigen::Matrix<double, 10, 1> a;
auto x = makeInputV(&a);
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/GqT936

**Edit:** Kind of a pet peeve: if it doesn't make sense to pass in a `nullptr` as argument to your class, then don't allow it. The signature of your `InputV` constructor tells me passing in an `Eigen::Matrix` is optional, and that passing in `nullptr` is perfectly fine.

If that's not the case, make your code such that something has to be passed in: `InputV (Eigen::Matrix<double, N, 1> const &)`. I.e. use a reference instead of a pointer.

The much inferior solution is documenting that you shouldn't pass in `nullptr` (and keeping the documentation up to date, and making sure whoever uses the code reads it, and ...). But why allow it to happen in the first place?

*Rant over :).*

Comment: Ahhh that is really neat, I didn't realize I could use auto so neatly, thanks!

Comment: Yes, `auto` is your friend. Well, it's mine, I'm sure some people will disagree :). It's kind of subjective. If you want to read some opinions, I suggest searching for "almost always auto", you'll find plenty of articles.

Comment: I generally agree, but want to say that a) You need to be careful with `auto` when expression templates are involved (e.g., `auto x = 2*a;` would not actually evaluate anything). And b) when passing as `const &`, you sometimes have to pay attention that you don't store the address of a temporary which goes out of scope early.

Comment: Yes, the problem with `auto` and expression template is in fact explicitly discussed [in the Eigen documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). Regarding `const &` arguments going out of scope, you could always create a `InputV (Eigen::Matrix<...> &&) = delete` constructor. That gives you a pretty foolproof solution.